# A case of import module from subdirectory - why does it work?

Tags: python, windows, pythonpath

I have a code from a friend (who works on Ubuntu) that is structured like this (no **init**.py files!):

```
BaseFolder
|-SubFolder1
  |- file1.py
  |- file2.py
|-SubFolder2
```

In file1.py there is an import:

```
from SubFolder1.file2 import func
```

She says it works when she runs the file1 from the BaseFolder. It doesn't works for me on Windows though; I read that the solution without any changes to either structure or files is to add path to the PYTHONPATH variable, but my question is if it is typical for Linux or she had modified the path?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the infomation concerning that - she probably stores the whole tree in a subdirectory of the working directory (the base Python dir) :)